# HopStop faultString when provided with coordinates instead of addresses

Tags: http, http-post, fault

From HopStop's documentation: http://www.hopstop.com/developer/?action=documentation#6.1.3

for the GetRoute function, it is stated that instead of providing the addresses, X1, X2, Y1, Y2 (longitude, lattitude) can be provided and that addresses are not required

but when executing

```
    http://www.hopstop.com/ws/GetRoute?licenseKey=LICENSE_KEY&X1=-73.9860&X2=-74.0062&Y1=40.7532&Y2=40.7617&day=1&time=9%3A00&mode=s
```

instead of:

```
    http://www.hopstop.com/ws/GetRoute?licenseKey=LICENSE_KEY&city1=newyork&address1=1800%20Broadway&city2=newyork&address2=162%20Madison%20Ave&day=1&time=9%3A00&mode=s
```

outputs:

```
    <ResponseStatus>
    <FaultCode>181</FaultCode>
    <FaultString>address1 and address2 not found.</FaultString>
    </ResponseStatus>
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is a bit outdated. There was a mistake with those parameters. They should be lowercase, so instead of X1, use x1. But I would suggest not using them as they are deprecated and at some point will be removed.

The address parameters will accept latitude and longitude like this:

```
address1=latitude,longitude
```

So the query should be: ( removed the license key )

```
http://www.hopstop.com/ws/GetRoute?licenseKey=MY_LICENSE_KEY&address1=40.7532,-73.9860&address2=40.7617,-74.0062&day=1&time=9%3A00&mode=s
```

Hope this helps!

Source: I work at HopStop.